Capturing uri from drag-and-drop from explorer to webview in a VS Code extension?
I have a webview made with React. I would like to implement a drag-and-drop thing, to allow dropping files from the vs-code explorer onto my webview.
So, in my react code I did a onDrop function, where I call:
event.preventDefault();
console.log(event);

The thing is, nowhere in the logged event do I find any mention of my dropped file uri (./todos.json or similar). How can I access that?
Comparing with dropping files from "finder" ie macs folders which works great. For those case I can find data in:
event.dataTransfer.files

But that one (and even event.nativeEvent.dataTransfer) is empty when dropping from vs-code's explorer.
Any ideas? What I can try here?

Call getData to reveal data:
  const everything = JSON.stringify({
    'dataTransfer.types': Array.from(event.dataTransfer.types),
    'dataTransfer.getData(text/uri-list)': event.dataTransfer.getData('text/uri-list'),
    'dataTransfer.getData(text/plain)': event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'),
    'dataTransfer.files.0.name': event.dataTransfer.files.item(0)?.name,
  }, null, 2);

  console.log('Dropped:', everything);

